# Customise Lightning component quick action without writing a new component

Tags: quickaction, lightning-quickaction

I've got a Lightning quick action that I'd like to package in my AppExchange package. It requires a custom name to be provided if default doesn't suit your needs.

Right now the alternative would be to write a custom component where it extends my abstract component and do something like `<aura:set attribute="someParam" value="foo123"/>`.

I'm trying to devise a way that same could be achieved without writing custom component. What comes to mind is using custom permission or Label, but those would be problematic if there's more than one quick action.

The easiest way would be if invoked component could access quick action name. Then the name (or field in action description) could be used as parameter itself.

Any ideas are welcome.

Comment: Seems like `lightning:quickActionAPI` and it's method `getSelectedActions` can reveal action name!

Comment: Note this doesn't work with global actions. Which don't support recordId also...